# How to share a library among several Dockerfiles and repos?

Tags: python, docker

I am working on a project that's evolved from one Dockerfile supporting several apps to one Dockerfile per app.

This generally works better than having them all together in one, but I'd like to share one Python library file among the apps without duplicating it.

I don't see a good way to do this, at least with the structure as currently set up: all apps have individual Bitbucket repos.

I don't think it's worth it to change the repo structure just for this, but is there some easier way I'm missing?

Comment: By share you mean you don't want to install library via pip multiple times to save space? You can mount volume with required library code and then point `PYTHONPATH` to it. I'd, however, not do it, as it's another moving part to manage (e.g. ensuring you always have mounted volume).

Comment: Your description is too abstract to give a practical advice. Share some details and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one dockerfile containing the basic stuff for all your applications.

To reuse the basic image you have to push the image to your registry. And then you can use this basic image in your application images

```
FROM yourrepo/baseimage:latest
```

The main issue with this solution will be that the image is not updated at runtime. So if you update the baseimage you have to rebuild all your application images.

So you should use a CI/CD pipeline if the number of application containers is growing.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what we tried first and had enough trouble with it moved to the "one dockerfile per repo" method which mostly worked better.